# Interfaces, business logic and global.asax with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autofac, n-tier-architecture

I'm trying to figure out how separation should work with ASP.NET and dependency injection.

I have four projects:

- ASP.NET Client
- BusinessLogic class lib (BL)
- Integration class lib, calling Service references
- Shared (Interfaces, Models)

In Integration I have a repository, which calls other services. The repository "MyRepository" implements an interface "IMyRepository", which is placed in Shared, and returns objects which are also placed in Shared.

Strictly speaking, I would not like a reference/dependency from the Client to the Integration-project, but all communication should happen through BL.

In the Client's Global.asax, I register my types with Autofac

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType<MyRepository>().As<IMyRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

However this requires the Client-project to reference the Integration-project for the implementation of MyRepository. Should it be this way?

How can I not have a reference from Client to Integration and keep the separation clean?

My real world project is on a much larger scale than this, so I'm trying to untangle the dependencies.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My normal approach is:

1. Define a way to discover types in each individual assembly. Easiest approach (if you do not mind referencing Autofac in each) is to put an Autofac `Module` in each assembly. If you do not like that, you can define your own discovery abstraction (for example, MEF-like attributes).
2. Discover all assemblies. Easiest approach is to scan the `bin` folder, but you can use some custom configuration. I haven't checked latest versions of Autofac add anything in terms of module discovery, but previously I did it manually.
3. Use previously defined type discovery approach to register all relevant types from each discovered assembly.